# Prime factors of $n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know it is unknown if there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. Is it known if there is a positive integer $k$ such that $|\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n^2+1 \text{ has at most k prime factors}\}|=\infty$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, Iwaniec, "Almost-primes represented by quadratic polynomials", Inventiones Math., 47:171–188, 1978, proves that there exist inﬁnitely many 
integers $n$ such that $n^2 + 1$ is either prime or the product of two 
primes.

Comment: Andres defeated me by 20seconds

Comment: I'm teaching number theory, so I had the reference in my desk. :-)

Comment: Oh, i googled it and got a reference. Nice to know anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Please see  Iwaniec, "Almost-primes represented by quadratic polynomials", Inventiones Math